# looping through 2 Json files with each 200k records in them

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, filter, reduce

I have 2 large json files with each 200k objects and when i try to loop between 2 jsons for a common id, it takes more time for execution.

**Implementation 1**

```
for (var i in matterData.data) {
  const fobj = matterData.data[i];

  const  ma_array = [];
  for (var j in activityData.data) {
    const aobj = activityData.data[j];
    if (fobj.id === aobj.matter.id) {
      ma_array.push(aobj);
    }
    if (ma_array.length > 0) fobj.activities = ma_array;
  }
}
```

**Implementation 2**

```
for (var i in matterData.data) {
  //Activities
  matters_array = [];
  matters_array = activityData.data.filter(function (el) {
    if (el.matter !== null) return el.matter.id == matterData.data[i].id;
  });
  if (matters_array.length > 0) matterData.data[i]["activities"] = matters_array;
}
```

**Implementation 3**

```
for (var i in matterData.data) {
  matters_array = [];

  for (var j in activityData.data) {
    if (activityData.data[j]["matter"] !== null) {
        if (matterData.data[i].id === activityData.data[j]["matter"].id) {
            matters_array.push(activityData.data[j]);
        }
        if (matters_array.length > 0) matterData.data[i]["activities"] = matters_array;
    }
  }
}
```

Every implementation is taking more time to execute.

ActivitiesData will have an id and also matter.id which is related to matterData.id

Any insights , please help

**Matters Data**

```
var matterData= {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1055395769,
      "description": "Peters",
      "status": "Pending",
      "location": null,
      "client_reference": "1532",
      "billable": true,
      "billing_method": "hourly",
      "open_date": "2019-06-05",
      "close_date": null,
}

]
};
```

**Activities Data**

```
var activityData = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id":285568423,
      "type": "ExpenseEntry",
      "date": "2011-01-01",
      "quantity_in_hours": 1,
      "rounded_quantity_in_hours": 1,
      "quantity": 1,
      "rounded_quantity": 1,
      "price": 100,
      "matter": {
        "id": 1055395769
      }
      },
      {
      "id": 285568428,
      "type": "MonEntry", 
      "matter": {
        "id": 1055395769
      }
      },
      {
      "id": 285568442,
      "type": "EEntry", 
      "matter": {
        "id": 1055395769
      }}]
    };
```

Comment: You might need to look at sorting the JSON by id first, although I am not sure what the ID looks like. If the ID is a number, once sorted, use a Binary Search algorithm. As for the sorting algorithm, that is up to you as there are a lot of options.

Answer (score 1):

First create a map containing id as the key and matter.data as value and create a empty array for acitvity then iterate over the activity and push activity in empty array

```
const map = {}
for( var i in matterData.data){
  map[matterData.data[i].id] = matterData.data[i];
  matterData.data[i].activities = [];
}

for(var i in activityData.data){
 var matter = map[activityData.data[i].matter.id];
 matter.activities.push(activityData.data[i]);
}
for( var i in matterData.data){
  console.log(matterData.data[i]);
}
```

This solution works only if matterData.data[i].id is unique

Answer (score 0):

You are running an O(n^2) loop which is nearly 200000*200000 loop. Thats huge calculation to handle. You can reduce this complexity by using map. Store all values  of `activityData.data` in map with id. And then iterate over one  `matterData.data` to check if the id exists in  map.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of [the answer with ruhul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590726/9986821)

```
const map = Object.create(null);
const res = [];

// Store all values of matterData.data in map with id.
matterData.data.forEach(item => (map[item.id] = item));

//  iterate over one  activityData.data to check if the id exists in map.
activityData.data.forEach(item => {
  const { id } = item;
    if (map[id]) {
    res.push(item);
   }
});
```

Comment: updated json for 2 objects..The above code needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

The Set.has is O(1) which, I think can be used efficiently for this purpose.

```
var subSet = new Set(activityData.data.map(obj => {obj.matter.id}));


for (var i in matterData.data) {

  const  ma_array = [];
  if (subSet.has(matterData.data[i].id){

     ...
  }  

}
```